Merge 2 rows data with common column
I like to merge 2 rows with same column id.
For example:
Data= {
'Rollnumber'   :    ['1001','1001'],    
'Details':    
['john alex' , 'texas'],
}

Output expected
Rollnumber    Details
1001    john alex texas


your example is not clear, extend the input data and desired output
